# Absolute Layout Xamarin Set Image

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin Forms and find out some strange thing I can't understand

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>

               
                    <Button Text="Ok" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 0.1, 0.33" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"></Button>
                    <Image Source="plan.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.1, 0, 0.8, 0.33" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
                    <Button Text="NotOk"  HorizontalOptions="End" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, 0.1, 0.33" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"></Button>
             
            
           
        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Thiss mark up not align image on center.It's overlay left button almost. But of I change image bounds to

```
 <Image Source="plan.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0, 0.8, 0.33" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
```

It placed as expected. I just want to know what I missed here.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Well the main factor that caused it is your layout flags "ALL" which represents that all values on your View are proportional and when you set it to 0.1 and 0 it started from X axis 0.1 and Y Axis 0 to 0.8 and 0.33. Hope you understood what i mean here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that when you want to align the image **horizontally centered**. You just need to set the `XProportional` which is the first digit to `0.5`. In other words, a position of `(0.5,0)` centers the child within the AbsoluteLayout in horizontal direction.

For more details, you can go through [Proportional positioning and sizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout#proportional-positioning-and-sizing).